# window.addEventListener does not work for empty windows

Tags: node.js, jsdom

JSDOM version : 0.6.5
Nitrous.io Cloud IDE environment

Issue observed:
Creating an empty Window and then attaching an event handler fails with exception trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Node' of undefined

at Object.DOMWindow.addEventListener (/home/action/workspace/Projects/nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:180:10)

at Request._callback (/home/action/workspace/Projects/nodejs/page_test_demo.js:22:14)

at Request.self.callback (/home/action/workspace/Projects/nodejs/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)

at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)

at Request. (/home/action/workspace/Projects/nodejs/node_modules/request/index.js:886:14)

at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)

at IncomingMessage. (/home/action/workspace/Projects/nodejs/node_modules/request/index.js:837:12)

at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)

at _stream_readable.js:910:16

at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
var window = jsdom.createWindow();
console.log(window);

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
console.log('Load event completed');
});

window.document = jsdom.jsdom(body);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing out here?

Comment: Can you bind it after? I'd imagine 'load' will fire asynchronously after `jsdom.jsdom(body)`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thank you for the note. In fact it does not load even after I try to bind it after jsdom.jsdom(body).Please refer to the below link that discusses a similar issue : https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/530.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you mention in your comment has fixed 7 months ago, so as long as you have a recent version of JSDOM, you should be able to do this:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var body = '<html><body></body></html>';

var document = jsdom.jsdom(body);
var window = document.createWindow();
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('Load event completed');
});
```

Comment: After reading and also trying a lot of stuff - I think you are correct. I would however like to point out that the above approach is not guaranteed to work for some websites whenever we do real life scraping. As a part of my experiments, I was using the 'request' module and loading the html response within jsdom. The 'load' event handler works well for sites like 'www.yahoo.com', but fails to work for 'www.google.com'. In case of 'www.google.com', the 'load' event is not triggered and my script waits forever. Do you have any idea why this is the case?